# Creating a Web Server for WebQuiz

Tags: online, webquiz

I am trying to create a quiz online using [WebQuiz](https://ctan.org/pkg/webquiz). I have created websites before using Wix, Google Sites, etc. but I have never created a web server before in this way. I need help in creating a web server so others can go to it online via a URL.

> **I have the file working on my desktop but how do I get it online?**

I have read the instructions multiple times. It states "Of course, the real reason for using WebQuiz is to create a web page for the quiz, which you do by processing the quiz using the webquiz command )instead of, say pdflatex)." On the toolbar under Quick Build, I see pdflatex but I do not see a webquiz option.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to drop down to a command line to build the HTML files using the webquiz command. This will generate a set of HTML and image files that you can then upload to any web server.

Comment: How exactly do I drop down to a command line? This is the part that is confusing me. For example, do I type \command{WebQuiz} or do I do something entirely different? Thank you for your help!

Comment: It depends on your computer. It looks like you're on Wndows so you'd go to the start menu and type cmd to open a DOS window (or whatever the kids are calling it these days. You will then use the CD command to get to your directory where the files are and then you can type `webquiz webquizdoc` Perhaps someone who deals with Windows regularly can give you better instructions.

Comment: On the Mac, I open the terminal command (most easily reached by doing cmd-space and typing terminal). Navigation is again by cd, but you can drag a folder into the terminal window to get the path you want to go to (maybe the equivalent action works in Windows?)

Comment: So, I typed in the following: C:\Users\Will>\Desktop\GeometryLesson\webquizdoc.tex
And it says "the system cannot find the path specified." Do you have any other advice? I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: try `cd Desktop\GeometryLesson` then `webquiz webquizdoc`

Comment: I am going to play around with it for a little bit. I really appreciate your help! This will get me started on doing it for sure!